# Braille graphics

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, unicode, binary-matrix

Cut a boolean matrix in 4x2 blocks and render them as Braille characters `U+2800`...`U+28FF`.

```
[[0,1,0,0,1,0],
 [1,0,0,0,0,0],
 [1,0,0,0,1,0],
 [1,1,1,1,0,0]]

⣎⣀⠅
```

Pad with 0-s if dimensions are not multiples of 4 and 2.

```
[[0,1,0],
 [1,0,0],
 [1,1,1]]

⠮⠄
```

Usual golfing rules apply, flexible on input format. Output should either have the structure of a matrix or look like a matrix, e.g. list of strings; single string with newlines.

Hint: `chr(0x2800 + 128*b7 + 64*b6 + 32*b5 + 16*b4 + 8*b3 + 4*b2 + 2*b1 + b0)` is the dot pattern

```
b0 b3
b1 b4
b2 b5
b6 b7
```

Larger test:

```
[[0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0],
 [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1],
 [0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1],
 [1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1],
 [1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0],
 [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0],
 [1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
 [1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
 [1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0],
 [1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0],
 [1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0],
 [0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0],
 [0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0],
 [0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0]]

⣰⠟⠻⣦⠀⠠⠾⡇⢠⡞⢛⡆
⣿⢠⣬⣥⠄⣀⠀⡇⢈⣻⣈⡀
⣿⠘⢹⡇⡞⠙⡇⣧⡉⢹⡏⠀
⠘⠷⠟⠁⠳⠾⠃⠘⠇⠾⠧⠀
```

Comment: Congrats on second challenge.

Comment: Better description: *you have a 2D array of Boolean values whose rows represents the horizontal raster lines of a black-and-white (1 bit per pixel) frame buffer or graphics canvas. Encode all of the 4x2 rectangular blocks of this canvas into Unicode Braille characters.  To handle fractional blocks at the edges, pad the canvas's width to a multiple of 2, and height to a multiple of four, with zeros (or otherwise ensure the equivalent output, treating the data as if it were so padded).*

Comment: @Kaz I don't know, I personally really appreciate how concise this post is. IMO, not a lot of clarity would be added by writing any more (besides a few small clarifications like noting that the height should be a mult of 4 and the width of 2); your suggestion is harder for me to read than the current post.

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>31</s>  30 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
sz0Z
ç€2ZF€ç€8Zœ?@€€-36Ḅ+⁽$ṁỌY
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7@4yiCK6/DyR01rjKLcgCSYaRF1dLK9A5ABRLrGZg93tGg/atyr8nBn48PdPZH///@PjjbQMdAxhEIDFIgsApWP1eFSiEaoR9WDzIfLI@nApQbVLogOdLtR3YUsaoihA5tPkO2G@QNTHboOJLOQdODyPRoLqw5UlxugmoZFB2o4YdiOosNAxxALiRaKWMPKEMnlGOFIlA5DDB3I7jDEFms4dGD62xDFXlQdBmjxgM5DCr3YWAA)**

#### How?

```
sz0Z - Link 1, split & right-pad with zeros: list, items; number, chunkSize
s    - split items into chunks of length chunkSize
 z0  - transpose with filler zero
   Z - transpose

ç€2ZF€ç€8Zœ?@€€-36Ḅ+⁽$ṁỌY - Main link: list of lists of numbers (1s & 0s), M
ç€2                       - call the last link (1) as a dyad for €ach (left=M, right=2)
                          -  ((left,right) bits read left-right then top-bottom)
   Z                      - transpose the resulting list of lists of lists
                          -  ((left, right) bits read top-bottom then left-right)
    F€                    - flatten €ach
      ç€8                 - call the last link (1) as a dyad for €ach (left=^, right=8)
         Z                - transpose the resulting list of lists of lists
                          -  ("blocks" each and all read left-right top-to bottom)
               -36        - literal -36
             €€           - for €ach (block-wise row) for €ach (block)
          œ?@             -   lexicographical permutation with reversed arguments
                          -    (get the permutation at index -36 (modular) in a list of
                          -     all permutations of the indexes sorted lexicographically.
                          -     That is the 8!-36 = 40284th - equivalently the values at
                          -     indexes [8,7,6,4,2,5,3,1])
                  Ḅ       - convert from binary list to integer (vectorises)
                    ⁽$ṁ   - base 250 literal = 10240
                   +      - add
                       Ọ  - cast to character (vectorises)
                        Y - join with newlines
                          - implicit print
```

Comment: Does `Ḅ` support "digits" greater than 1? Instead of adding 10240 (0x2800 - two bytes) to the result, you could prepend 40 (0x28 - one byte) to the vector of binary digits. I don't know much about Jelly, so I'm not sure if this would really work.

Comment: `Ḅ` would indeed convert a leading digit of 40 as you suggest, but we'd need to prepend it to *each* such list (at a depth of 2) which, I think, would require more bytes of code (`;@€€40Ḅ`).

Answer (score 7):

## Mathematica, <s>126</s> <s>110</s> <s>97</s> 90

```
FromCharacterCode[10240+ListCorrelate[2^{{0,3},{1,4},{2,5},{6,7}},#,1,0][[;;;;4,;;;;2]]]&
```

---

This solution takes advantage of [`ListCorrelate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListCorrelate.html) to [convolve a (reversed) kernel over a matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)#Convolution), which is essentially a sliding matrix multiplication (or dot product). See a visual explanation [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64925/how-do-i-understand-listcorrelatecontains-k-l-k-r-when-it-works-for-2-di?noredirect=1&lq=1). Padding is done by using `0` as the fourth argument. In the following example, we expect the result to match the hint above:

```
ListCorrelate[
  2^{{0, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 5}, {6, 7}},
  {{b0, b3}, {b1, b4}, {b2, b5}, {b6, b7}}
]

(* returns {{b0 + 2 b1 + 4 b2 + 8 b3 + 16 b4 + 32 b5 + 64 b6 + 128 b7}} *)
```

Note that `ListConvolve` is not any shorter, since the third argument would be `-1`.

Since this applies the kernel at every position of the matrix, we just need to extract the elements in every fourth row and second column. We use shorthands for [`Span`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Span.html) and [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html): `[[;;;;4,;;;;2]]`.

Helpfully, [`FromCharacterCode`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FromCharacterCode.html) can take a matrix of character codes and return a list of strings.

---

This solution returns a list of strings, which is one of the allowed output formats. Simply prepend `Column@` for the output to “look like a matrix.”

---

You can play around with this in a free online Mathematica notebook. [Go here](https://develop.open.wolframcloud.com/app/), click Create a New Notebook, wait a moment, paste in this code, then press <kbd>shift+enter</kbd>.

```
m1={{0,1,0,0,1,0},{1,0,0,0,0,0},{1,0,0,0,1,0},{1,1,1,1,0,0}};
m2={{0,1,0},{1,0,0},{1,1,1}};
m3={{0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0},{0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1},{1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1},{1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0},{1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},{1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0},{1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},{1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0},{1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0},{1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0},{0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0},{0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0},{0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0}};

MatrixToBraille := Column@
  FromCharacterCode[10240+ListCorrelate[2^{{0,3},{1,4},{2,5},{6,7}},#,1,0][[;;;;4,;;;;2]]]&

MatrixToBraille/@{m1,m2,m3}
```

Then you should see this:

> [image]

Comment: (recently Wolfram cloud requires user sign in, but that code works on TIO as well; however I didn't figure out how to get it to print Unicode characters)

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript ES7 <s>210</s> <s>207</s> <s>201</s> <s>200</s> <s>198</s> <s>194</s> <s>185</s> 183 bytes

```
a=>eval('for(y=0,c="";A=a[y];y+=4,c+=`\n`)for(x=0;A[x]+1;x+=2)c+=String.fromCharCode(10240+eval("for(N=k=0;k<6;k++)N+=(g=(X,Y=3)=>(a[Y+y]||0)[X+x]|0)(k>2,k%3)*2**k")|g(0)+g(1)*2<<6)')
```

4 bytes saved thanks to ngn

3 bytes saved thanks to Luke

## How it works

I'm going to split the code up into parts and speak about them separately:

```
for(y=x=0, c=""; a[y]; x+=2)
    !((a[y] || [])[x]+1) && (y+=4,x=0,c+=`\n`)
```

This is where every variable gets declared. `x` and `y` is the position of the "cursor" (the upper left edge of the current braille character). The x coordinate increases by 2 every iteration, and it stops, when there's no row with the index `y` (a[x] returns `undefined` if it doesn't exist, which gets converted to false).

There are multiple tricks in the second row. `(a[y] || [])[x]` ensures that looking up the value at the `(x, y)` position doesn't throw an error. The `&&` is the usual and operator, and it only checks the right side of the expression, if the left was true. This can be translated to

```
if (!((a[y] || [])[x] + 1)) 
    y+=4,x=0,c+=`\n`
```

The next part:

```
c+=String.fromCharCode(10240+eval("for(N=k=0;k<6;k++)N+=(g=(x,y)=>(a[y]||[])[x]||0)(~~(k/3)+x,k%3+y)*2**k,N")+g(x,y+3)*64+g(x+1,y+3)*128)
```

`String.fromCharCode` simply converts the passed number to a unicode character with the same character code. The expression in the parentheses calculates the index of the Braille character:

```
for(N=k=0;k<6;k++)N+=(g=(x,y)=>(a[y]||[])[x]||0)(~~(k/3)+x,k%3+y)*2**k
```

Goes through the position in the

```
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

order, multiplies the values at those positions with 2<sup>i</sup>, where i is the index and adds them together. The

```
g=(x,y)=>(a[y]||[])[x]||0
```

part declares a lambda function called `g`, which given an `x` and `y` coordinate returns either the value at the `(x, y)` position or 0 if the position lies outside the bounds of the array.

```
+g(x,y+3)*64+g(x+1,y+3)*128
```

This part adds up the last two positions with the correct weights using the function defined a bit earlier.

Last but not least, the

```
a=>eval('...')
```

part has 2 functions. It defines an anonymous lambda and ensures, that the for loop doesn't cause any problems (a single line lambda such as this one can't contain a single for loop only, an evaluation circumvents this).

Comment: a few simple suggestions: `||0` -> `|0`; `~~(k/3)` -> `(k>2)`; `*128` -> `<<7` (replacing `+`-s with `|`-s)

Comment: Why not submit the ES7 version as your primary solution?

Comment: @Shaggy Not everyone can run ES7 yet, so it's a backup

Comment: That's irrelevant 'round these parts ;) As long as there is one, single interpreter (browser) that can run your code properly, it's considered to be valid here.

Comment: @ngn Thanks for the first two, but bit shifting has a lower precedence than basically anything, so that won't work

Comment: @Shaggy I started with ES6, but then realized I could save a couple of bytes with a technique and I could utilize ES7 there, but here you go, removed

Comment: Sorry, shaky hands on a touchscreen posted my last comment before I could add: Submit the ES7 one as your main solution and, if you feel it's worth it, the ES6 one as the backup.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks, forgot to add the next one

Comment: I saved 10 bytes: `a=>eval('for(y=x=0,c="";A=a[y]||[];A[x+=2]<0||(y+=4,x=0,c+="\n"))c+=String.fromCharCode(10240+eval("for(N=k=0;++k<6;)N+=(g=(X,Y=3)=>(a[Y+y]||[])[X+x]|0)(k>2,k%3)*2**k")+g(0)*64+g(1)*128)')`

Comment: @Bálint as I mentioned in brackets, for `<<7` you'd have to replace some `+`-s with `|`-s: `...+g(0,3)*64+g(1,3)*128...` -> `...|g(0,3)*64|g(1,3)<<7...`; shifting has higher precedence than bitwise or - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table

Comment: @Luke that doesn't really work. If you insert `||[]` after `A=a[y]`, then the loop won't stop. Thanks for the `Y=3` one though

Comment: @ngn Right, fixed

Answer (score 5):

## Dyalog APL, <s>133</s> <s>122</s> <s>114</s> <s>112</s> <s>101</s> <s>100</s> <s>98</s> <s>95</s> <s>94</s> <s>93</s> <s>90</s> <s>88</s> 86 bytes

Assumes `⎕IO←0`

```
{C⍴{⎕UCS 10240+2⊥(∊S⌷⍨⍵+⍳¨A)[⍎¨⍕76531420]}¨(,b)/,⍳⍴b←{0 0≡A|⍵}¨⍳⍴S←⍵↑⍨A×C←⌈(⍴⍵)÷A←4 2}
```

-<s>8</s> <s>9</s> 12 bytes thanks to @Adám in chat

-2 bytes thanks to @ngn

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU87CsJAEO33FFsmuOLko9YhELCyCKIgFopgI2grmlaiuKKFWFsI6VXSx5vMReKLwcjA7vvMm9kdL@f16Wo8X8zynI@XTpe3JxKij8uVLdZPUpYiVZ4loor/9bLAxQBJRzpV8pdGCSECuGsf5hrLen4oLbJdqtm8vxsc70M@pKwT1q8a60eWeOaQ9TGDcGm3mo7l2jSKssRQE7Oh0IFBk2IiSeLdzdsgGBXdhRHCAOftGRO999Uv@CE2YEE236n3/aMdCTwFMJD9Cg1Enn8A)

### How (input is `⍵`)?

- `A←4 2`, store the vector `4 2` in variable `A`
- `(⍴⍵)÷`, the dimensions of `⍵` divided by `A`
- `⌈`, ceiling
- `C←`, stored in `C`
- `A×`, multiplied by `A`
- `⍵↑⍨`, fit `⍵` to those dimensions
- `S←`, stored in `S`
- `⍳⍴`, indexes of `S`
- `{0 0≡A|⍵}¨`, `1` where the top left of a cell is, `0` everywhere else
- `(,b)/,⍳⍴b←`, truthy indexes
- `{⎕UCS 10240+2⊥(∊S⌷⍨⍵+⍳¨A)[⍎¨⍕76531420]}¨`, turn each element into braille
- `C⍴`, reshape the dimensions to `C`

Comment: consider `+/(2*0 3 1,A,4+⍳3)×something` → `2⊥something[⍎¨⍕76524130]`

Comment: WOuld that still work now that I changed it to `⎕IO←0`?

Comment: Actually, it would _only_ work in `⎕IO←0` :)

Comment: I tried that, am I doing something wrong? https://tio.run/##RU87CsJAEO33FFsmuOLko9YhELCyCKIgFopgI2grmlaiuKKFWFsI6VXSx5vMReKLwcjA7vvMm9kdL@f16Wo8X8zynI@XTpe3JxKij8uVLdZPUpYiVZ4loor/9bLAxQBJRzpV8pdGCSECuGsf5hrLen4oLbJdqtm8vxsc70M@pKwT1q8a60eWeOaQ9TGDcGm3mrZrOTSKssRQE7Oh0IFBk2IiSeLdzdsgGBXdhRHCAOftGRO999Uv@CE2YEE236n3/aMdCTwFMJD9Cg3y/AM

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about this stupid thing (`⎕IO`) in APL. For `⎕IO←1`, of course you'd have to add 1 to each digit of 76524130.

Comment: Are those `something`'s different?

Comment: It seems `something` is fine, but the permutation (76524130) must be different.

Comment: it should work with 76531420

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/) + [drawille](https://github.com/asciimoo/drawille), <s>141</s> <s>125</s> <s>120</s> 116 bytes

Saved 16 bytes thanks to ngn and L3viathan

Saved 5 bytes thanks to L3viathan

Saved 4 bytes thanks to ngn

```python
from drawille import*
def a(d,c=Canvas(),e=enumerate):[c.set(j,i)for i,x in e(d)for j,y in e(x)if y];print c.frame()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jcc7DsIwDADQnVN4jFHUgRHUiWMgBiuxhavmIzeU5vRBgre92tur5MsYYiVBNProujJoqsXa@RRZgFz0Yb5T3mlz6Hnm/E5s1BivjzBt3NziFaUYqD9AM7CLvy6@/3ugCvTnrZrmBmESo8QOx/gC)

tio does not have drawille installed so it does not work

Comment: Python and its batteries! :) Doesn't fail to surprise me. You can shrink this to under 120 bytes if you use `enumerate()` and a list comprehension.

Comment: Save a couple of bytes by making the function a one-liner: `def b(d,c=l.Canvas()):print([c.set(j,i)for i,x in enumerate(d)for j,y in enumerate(x)if y]and c).frame()`

Comment: [Got it to 120 bytes](https://pastebin.com/wmBTYvhG)

Comment: you don't need the `and c` trick - the comprehension could be a statement on its own followed by `;print c.frame()`

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, 136 bytes

```
a=>(b=a.map(x=>[]),a.map((l,i)=>l.map((c,j)=>b[i>>2][j>>1]|=c<<'01263457'[i%4+j*4%8])),b.map(l=>l.map(c=>String.fromCharCode(10240+c))))
```

Thanks to [ngn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/24908/ngn), using bit shifts save 4 bytes.

Comment: you can use bit shifts like `i/4|0` -> `i>>2`

Comment: `c*2**` is a bit shift, too :)

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>57</s> 54 bytes*

-3 thanks to OP. Prompts for Boolean matrix. Prints character matrix.

```apl
1↓⎕UCS{2⊥40,⌽(,⍉3↑⍵),⊢⌿⍵}⌺(2 2⍴4 2)⊢0⍪⍣3⍪∘0⍣3⊢⎕,0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVLBSsQwEL33K3LchQhJW39Abx7qYfFUeihskUKpy@4KStlrraUpihS86EERxKt6EWTBT5kfqW123SZpCjKQzmTmvZl5qT@L9qaXfnR2WkN2dTD3wygKagrpHZTVyeEkMSF/sQmG4nuEgV1bkN4C@xxjyJ@gWDfuCoqvkYlMYB82MsfNPQH2BuzZaj/ZPeFuU11WmLRNDCe4WEJ6k7RUZXU0OXYgyxNgj6ufV2DvLScC9oDmgT9FcVOMHBSFcbBA/gKF8ex8WW8H5VTINlyXYIoJ5qeHDeRuIm5S3OU31uY9Q6Kz/ug6YAdRi@k@ryZYIBRMvNnmOVdXL2PEeJcXEEM1ci@6m1c3x1YGLDEqCN0mYm9RRjJgPS4BMbS94mkR8uREZtMgZJ163SUEwVRzKipqtRJ@MNzT8V8I2kOIc1Ddqw0g@ntTqa@MIMo7qJGgnuf9Ag)

`⎕,0` append a zero on right (ignored if even number of columns)

`⊢` yield that (to separate `3` and `⎕`)

`⍪∘0⍣3` append zeros on bottom thrice (because `⌺` drops partial windows)

`0⍪⍣3` stack zeros on top thrice (because `⌺` starts in the top left corner)

`⊢` yield that (separates the parenthesis and the `0`)

`{`…`}⌺(2 2⍴4 2)` on each 4-row 2-column window, with 4-row vertical and 2 row horizontal step:

`⊢⌿⍵` last row (lit. vertical right reduction); `[b6,b7]`

`(`…`),` prepend:

`3↑` take three rows; `[[b0,b3],[b1,b4],[b2,b5]]`

`⍉` transpose; `[[b0,b1,b2],[b3,b4,b5]]`

`,` ravel; `[b0,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5]`

now we have `[b0,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7]`

`⌽` reverse; `[b7,b6,b5,b4,b3,b2,b1,b0]`

`40,` prepend 40 (for 40×2<sup>9</sup> = 10240); `[40,b7,b6,b5,b4,b3,b2,b1,b0]`

`2⊥` evaluate as base-2 (binary)

`⎕UCS` convert to character

`1↓` drop the first row (all-zero because of `⌺`'s padding)

---

* In Classic, counting `⌺` as `⎕U233A`.

Comment: There's an easy way to save a few bytes, see my comment under the Jelly solution.

Comment: There must be a mistake - the TIO link doesn't match the code you posted here.

Comment: it's the zero-padding code near the end: `0⍪⍣3⍪∘0⍣3⊢⎕,0` vs `0⍪∘0⍣3⊢⎕,0`

Comment: @ngn Fixed, but I have a feeling that `⍪∘0⍣3` and `,0` are only needed due to a bug in `⌺`, and the first one isn't needed for your test cases.

Comment: My test cases aren't exhaustive - the solution should, of course, work for any valid input. You can shorten `0⍪⍣3⍪∘0⍣3⊢⍵,0` to `0(⊖⍪)⍣6⊢⍵,0`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 145 bytes

```hs
(a!b)c=take b$c++repeat a
r([]:_)=[]
r l=['⠀'..]!!(sum.zipWith(*)[1,8,2,16,4,32,64,128]$l>>=0!2):r(drop 2<$>l)
b[]=[]
b s=r(([]!4)s):b(drop 4s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZPPaoQwEMbvPsUIwibdIImVZZHGe8899BBCiVvblc26EvXSUx@lz9YXsS6VbRIVSiDkz/zmm/lCjqo9lVoP7xf9BjwAEIISStg0qDPsk@lejggRf4AL2fvbvY2sBblqE@LLu6XZp2yOLHVjq996mQf6iJXMRtYs8FbLiFs9ddMtIa5bM30XoYQtzJ6Xy44xq/qZm/9D2ByxS2FLz7eGzJtnjrKHUO89/J3loZSQZUI81p2UA1JhgQ@8U6cSiuiw3ZqyKVUHKjBIyOwFcyEDA5qLzffX5yaOZRiitj/HH1XzXHVHdIdHW/YkIWxHUnKfkF1KWLKXkc5zTsMEZwa9mksDyUOUaxwUQl5TFtByg0aJMMUtzorfmLTFw1lVNXBATd89dSbua13VZYsBFXD9u3j4AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>168</s> <s>165</s> 161 bytes

```python
def f(m):
 while m:
  r,m,s=[*zip(*m)],m[4:],''
  while r:s+=chr(10240+sum(q<<int(w)for(q,w)in zip((r[0]+(0,)*3)[:4]+(r+[()])[1],'01263457')));r=r[2:]
  print(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVTNboMwDL7zFNyalBzslm0SKw/QZ4g4bUNFGv0Jnart5RmFDuLYcJgQKMH@/DmfHZ@/r4fTcdu27x9lXKpaZ1F8O1SfH3HdrWJnatPkdv1TndW61oWpbZoVZrXqbIOby5okfzs4hbBJIWm@anXZ7arjVd10eXLqYm66Osb3AMpZKBIFRq@32mZpt3aJVbrQFruYgJvnbfr0stJav7rc2U1WdDRndw/W6HafWwsGDZj@W5gotsOuf8h@sg/P3V5EUan2OoqGiN1ijDhhJ9SMP/bRh@8fF3p/0H/6aODZkfiDh5Kynrx8f8oT6oCyl48fswIhvpSdnxWEZwxYH/agGsg0YNwLWUmKw8gRVoRnJPcMkpfmOtofWfFKh/7jH3IOKX@kSnldAkJ3ANPa50BBnbCetK8oP1cBSQUh6GyYqTqSmmOgi8y6dCchPDHRkZyS3DFkPMjuKQrq8btMquepx/MAVllkCOkktHuAcYCICDsN2dThCFhE0MyDjhMQyzOPcgCbfMBVFLWitxT/gUCGANaTQdVmEPPzEYUJBkEdwp0/ux/93/4C)

Comment: Nicely golfed! You can save three bytes with `[*zip(*m[:4])]` instead of calling `list`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 169 bytes

```python
a=[]
y=0
for l in eval(input()):
 y-=1;a+=y%4//3*[-~len(l)//2*[10240]];x=0
 for v in l:a[-1][x//2]|=v<<(6429374>>y%4*6+x%2*3&7);x+=1
for l in a:print(*map(chr,l),sep='')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZLfaoMwFMbvfYrcdE38g4lKS7Xpi4RchOGokFmxThTGXt3Zweg0J1kpnAuN5/zO5/elGbvzpU6nSXEhvZFT7@3SIo2qGpW90riqm48OE5J7aIw4K1TAx00Wx6kvoi9d1liTOE58wWiSUSmLYSagG6K/IXSuRMSkGOYe@cn74xHvsuSQ7rPTacb4u2DYJH76sifFEHB2363ypq3qDvvvqsGv5zbUJLyWDd9uyTQJQUM0F/tTFCrz071fhkisGCDJPF/0LzCPTIDKfjA2teB/mQ0MxrjtMRX/euOYs2HW2xaYR4yGX10Y0AYKLrRiwIysotcYuhwyH@BAXUkxwwZrps9gGIwx9TP3ZfsH4/CXQVoNDLXcFdvhOkQpvwE)

Comment: You can rewrite `if y%4<1:a+=-~len(l)//2*[10240],` as `a+=(y%4<1)*[-~len(l)//2*[10240]]` and fit `x=0;y+=1` on the same line. I think it saves a byte.

Comment: @ngn saved a few more bytes from there on out, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 53 bytes

```apl
4 2∘{⎕ucs 2⊥40⍪(⍎¨⍕76531420)∘.⊃,¨⍺∘↑¨↓∘⍵¨⍺∘×¨⍳⌈⍺÷⍨⍴⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVLLSsNAFN3nK2apMMpMm@o/uIgLlyGLYFMJhLSYFpTQlRBCcIoiRTe6E8StiuDS/sn9kXjzaDOTTEAuDPdxzrmPxJ0FB@NrN5he5LBa@1NI7lg@wZeYZADpU4zZxXmEfvZqMhDveyBWv28g1sdHoyE3B2wfUYeQ3dAi@4MBJPfoJg@FK7622c1j4X3AbYrx5hsERp9YX@aWdzXHhjHysNnJ2akFaRaDeFlWDMQQEM/k0nPHJEQwsUjgh15E3Ij44WwxzyekECGmYduMcspo@TrUIHYVlabETb2you4YtdBwK9RQGnAD46MSx6gkIpmcqeulSoNXOXK8q0uMPozai@8m1c1Rr04VxRZDt4ncWz4d67GOlsTo277laRnq5ExV0zDUO3W6KwxGueZtXVF7K@mnop07/ovBOwx5Dq77aj2M7t5c6asyWOs7tCPpeo7zBw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 164 bytes

163 bytes of code + 1 flag `-p`

```perl
@a=eval}{for(;$r<@a;$r+=4){for($c=0;$c<@{$a[0]};$c+=2){$n="0b";map$n.=0|$a[$r+3][$c+$_],1,0;for$y(1,0){map$n.=0|$a[$r+$_][$c+$y],2,1,0}$\.=chr 0x2800+oct$n}$\.=$/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZH/SsMwEMdfRcb90dKsXqoDoQv0BXyCGiSWicJsSx3iqH11462TevkxkEC43H3u1zf9bthvrK2M2n2Y/TQ@d0NSwrCtDN2Zuk1nDzQKS2i21QimRj2RnakiHaFVK3xalW@mhzZX@EVhSrvRNQHwqIUUWFIBOCZkpaPHETGDRy2KEzrBQ66al@EKP4s7xKxrDtDOTrierE1qFEjc@aBzuOc3rkX9R7sZ/L3EF/4S4fY58X5XdyLulR4f24D3Pc8fUj7PKi38pZ09K8K7E6NbK@BdbYLOjEchI7enXEQfySYOtPsHLz2eTyBjfxTlw22l05Pz6Onuv5hiOv3u@sNr177b9f0mR4l23f8A)

Takes each row comma separated on one line.