# Boolean Rectangles

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, matrix

*Inspired by [Braille graphics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/140624/42963)*

Given a Boolean matrix (i.e., consisting of only `1`s and `0`s), output an ASCII-art-style Unicode representation of the closed-polygon shape created by the `1`s in the matrix, using the Unicode drawing characters `┌ ─ ┐ │ └ ┘` (code points `0x250c, 0x2500, 0x2510, 0x2502, 0x2514,` and `0x2518,` respectively, separated by spaces). Replace the `0`s with spaces, so you're left with just the line drawing. Output or return that drawing.

You won't have to handle invalid or ambiguous input - there will be only one unambiguous path of `1`s through the matrix. In other words, every `1` has exactly two cardinal neighbors that are `1`s, and two that are `0`s or out of bounds. Additionally, since the shape is a closed-polygon, this guarantees that the path is cyclical.

Examples:

```
[[1,1,1]
 [1,0,1]
 [1,1,1]]

┌─┐
│ │
└─┘

[[0,1,1,1,1,0],
 [1,1,0,0,1,1],
 [1,0,0,0,0,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1,1]]

 ┌──┐
┌┘  └┐
│    │
└────┘

[[1,1,1,0,0]
 [1,0,1,1,1]
 [1,0,0,0,1]
 [1,1,0,1,1]
 [0,1,1,1,0]]

┌─┐
│ └─┐
│   │
└┐ ┌┘
 └─┘

[[1,1,1,0]
 [1,0,1,1]
 [1,1,0,1]
 [0,1,1,1]]

┌─┐
│ └┐
└┐ │
 └─┘
```

- Leading or trailing newlines or whitespace are all optional, so long as the characters themselves line up correctly.
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable. If a function, you can return the output rather than printing it.
- If possible, please include a link to an online testing environment so other people can try out your code!
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: What are the codepoints for the relevant drawing characters?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Good point. Added.

Comment: I believe this is a dupe since my Jelly solution works with this input [TIO](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzmkPdywxsNZ@uKPr8HSuRw1zDm09tDmwzlXR/VHjjoc7pz/cuTrmUcPMhzuazQy1LU3MDR/u7nnUuE9ZIYsr6vDER01rTA5Pj9LWBjMf7u4@tCjy////0dGGOiBooGMQq8OlEA1igUXgPBCE8aCyYB5UHVBfLAA). It could probably be shortened since there will only be one path here instead of multiple like in the other.

Comment: @miles Dagnabbit. I thought this was a duplicate, but 48+ hours in the Sandbox and several searches by me didn't find one.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork The usual tip: after you type the title, a list with possible duplicates goes below the title. You can check there, although the titles in this case were quite different.

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript (ES6), 125 bytes

```js
a=>a.map((r,i)=>r.map((c,j)=>c&&"─ ┌└  ┐┘ |"[!(a[i-1]||0)[j]+!(a[i+1]||0)[j]*2+!r[j-1]*4+!r[j+1]*8-3]||" ").join``).join`
`
```

Example code snippet:

```js
f=
a=>a.map((r,i)=>r.map((c,j)=>c&&"─ ┌└  ┐┘ |"[!(a[i-1]||0)[j]+!(a[i+1]||0)[j]*2+!r[j-1]*4+!r[j+1]*8-3]||" ").join``).join`
`
o.innerText=f([[1,1,1,0,0],
[1,0,1,1,1],
[1,0,0,0,1],
[1,1,0,1,1],
[0,1,1,1,0]])
```

```html
<pre id=o>
```