# Decode Faux Braille

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, unicode, binary-matrix

```
⢣⠃⢎⠆⣇⡇⡯⡂⠈⡏⢰⢵⢐⡭⢸⠪⡀⢸⢐⡭⠀⢹⠁⢎⠆⢸⣱⢸⡃⢎⠰⡱⢸⣱⢸⡃⠈⡏⢸⡃⡱⡁⢹⠁⢸⡀⡇⡗⢅⢸⡃⠈⡏⢸⢼⢸⢐⡭⠀

⣇⢸⡃⢹⠁⢹⠁⣟⢸⢕⢐⡭⠀⡮⡆⡯⡂⣟⠀⡯⠰⡱⢸⣸⢸⢕⠀⣏⡆⢎⠆⢹⠁⣪⠅⢸⢼⢸⠰⣩⢸⢼⠀⡮⡆⡗⢼⢸⣱⠀⢎⠆⡯⠀⢇⠇⡮⡆⡯⡂⡇⡮⡆⣟⡆⣇⢸⡃⠸⡰⡸⢸⢸⣱⠈⡏⢸⢼⠀

⢎⠆⡗⢼⢸⡃⢸⡃⡗⠔⡇⡯⠂⢹⠁⢣⠃⠸⡸⢸⡃⡯⡂⢹⠁⡇⢎⢰⢵⢸⡀⢸⡀⡇⡗⢼⢸⡃⢐⡭⢸⡃⡯⠂⡮⡆⡯⡂⡮⡆⢹⠁⣟⢐⡭⠀⢎⢸⢼⢰⢵⢸⢕⢰⢵⠰⡁⢹⠁⣟⢸⢕⢐⡭⠀

⡮⡆⢐⡭⢸⠕⢰⢵⠰⡁⣟⠀⡇⣪⠅⢈⣝⢸⡃⡯⡂⢎⠆⠸⡰⡸⢸⢸⣱⠈⡏⢸⢼⠀

⣪⠅⢎⠆⢸⠈⡏⠀⣇⠰⡱⠰⡱⢸⠪⡀⣪⠅⢸⡀⡇⡗⢅⢸⡃⠸⡰⡸⠰⡱⢸⢕⢸⣱⢐⡭⠀⡮⡆⡯⡂⣟⠀⣪⠅⣟⢸⠕⢰⢵⢸⢕⢰⢵⠈⡏⢸⡃⣏⡆⢸⣳⠘⡜⠀⢹⠁⢇⢆⠇⢎⠆⢸⡀⡇⡗⢼⢸⡃⣪⠅

⡇⡗⢼⢸⠕⢸⣸⠈⡏⠀⡇⣪⠅⢰⢵⠀⣪⠅⢹⠁⡯⡂⡇⡗⢼⠰⣩⠀⢎⠰⡱⢸⠢⡇⢹⠁⡮⡆⡇⡗⢼⢸⢸⠢⡇⢎⡅⢸⠅⡮⡆⣇⡇⡱⡁⢸⣳⢸⢕⢰⢵⢸⢸⡀⣇⢸⡃⠰⡱⢸⠅

⢎⠆⡗⢼⢸⡀⢣⠃⢸⡃⡗⢼⠰⣩⢸⡀⡇⣪⠅⡧⡇⢸⣸⢸⠕⢸⠕⢸⡃⡯⡂⢎⢰⢵⢐⡭⢸⡃⢸⡀⣟⠈⡏⠈⡏⢸⡃⡯⡂⣪⠅⢰⢵⢸⠢⡇⣏⡆⢐⡭⢸⠕⢰⢵⠰⡁⣟⢐⡭⠀

⡮⡆⣟⡆⢎⢸⣱⢸⡃⡯⠰⣩⢸⢼⢸⢀⠇⡗⢅⢸⡀⡗⠔⡇⡗⢼⠰⡱⢸⠕⠰⣩⡆⡯⡂⣪⠅⢹⠁⣇⡇⢇⠇⢇⢆⠇⡱⡁⢣⠃⣩⡃

⢎⠆⣇⡇⢹⠁⡯⠂⣇⡇⢹⠁⢸⠢⢺⢰⢵⠘⡜⠀⣟⡆⣟⠀⣇⡇⡯⠂⡯⠂⣟⢸⢕⠀⢎⠆⡯⡂⢸⡀⢎⠆⢇⢆⠇⣟⢸⢕⠰⡁⡮⡆⣪⠅⣟⠀

⣪⠅⡧⡇⢎⠆⡯⡂⢹⠁⣟⢐⡭⠈⡏⠀⢇⢆⠇⡇⡗⢼⢐⡭⠀

⡗⢼⠰⡱⠀⣇⠰⡱⠰⡱⢸⠕⢸⢼⠰⡱⢸⡀⣟⢐⡭⠀
```

[ASCII version of the above](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/149119/#comment364435_149119)

[`⡯⡂⣟⢸⡀⡮⡆⢹⠁⣟⢸⣱⠀`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/140624/braille-graphics)

## About Braille characters

A Braille character packs a 4 by 2 rectangle of dots, which can be viewed as a Boolean matrix.

The concatenation of all such matrices is a 4 by 2*n boolean matrix, where n is the length of the input string.

You should look for vertical lines without any dots in them, and use those as separators to split the big matrix into smaller matrices for each character.

Then, look for patterns to convert them to letters of the English alphabet or spaces. Note that after removing the separators (vertical empty lines), a space is a 4 by 0 matrix.

Below is a description of the alphabet in ASCII:

```
A   | B   | C  | D   | E  | F  | G   | H   | I | J  | K    | L  | M     | N    | O   | P   | Q    | R   | S   | T   | U   | V   | W     | X   | Y   | Z
----+-----+----+-----+----+----+-----+-----+---+----+------+----+-------+------+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+-----+-----+----
.#. | ##. | .# | ##. | ## | ## | .## | #.# | # | .# | #.#. | #. | #...# | #..# | .#. | ##. | .##. | ##. | .## | ### | #.# | #.# | #...# | #.# | #.# | ###
#.# | ### | #. | #.# | ## | #. | #.. | #.# | # | .# | ##.. | #. | ##.## | ##.# | #.# | #.# | #..# | #.# | #.. | .#. | #.# | #.# | #.#.# | .#. | #.# | ..#
### | #.# | #. | #.# | #. | ## | #.# | ### | # | .# | #.#. | #. | #.#.# | #.## | #.# | ##. | #.## | ##. | .## | .#. | #.# | #.# | #.#.# | .#. | .#. | .#.
#.# | ### | .# | ### | ## | #. | .## | #.# | # | #. | #..# | ## | #...# | #..# | .#. | #.. | .### | #.# | ##. | .#. | ### | .#. | .#.#. | #.# | .#. | ###
```

## Specification

- The input is a sequence of Unicode code points in the range U+2800..U+28FF represented as the usual string type in your language (e.g. char array, char pointer) in any popular encoding supported (UTF-8, UCS-2, etc).
- Trailing spaces in the output are fine.

---

*EDIT:* apologies to those whose browsers misrender the dots, it's supposed to look like this (image):
[image: faux-braille]

Comment: your task is to decode text like this / letters are four dots high and of variable width / one empty vertical line separates characters / a space is zero width / so it looks like words are separated by two lines / input is a string containing faux braille of / only english uppercase letters and spaces / abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz / output may be upper or lowercase / shortest wins / no loopholes / related

Comment: [Braille patterns](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/2800-28FF)

Answer (score 14):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>181</s> <s>179</s> <s>171</s> <s>167</s> <s>161</s> 159 bytes

Input by UTF-16 little-endian bytes without BOM. First decompose into columns using bit shifts, split by empty column, then hash them into a lookup table.

*-2 bytes thanks to [ngn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/24908/ngn).

-5 bytes thanks to [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder).*

```python
lambda h,j=''.join:j(' ZAQV;JWP;MBOS;YRKCGXDF;ILHUENT'[int('0'+i,27)%544%135%32]for i in j(chr(64|i&7|i>>3&8)+chr(64|i>>3&7|i>>4&8)for i in h[::2]).split('@'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDLTsJAFN37Fd3AtAGJQAFTAvH9fr8VWSCPUIItQVyYsAAJ4EpdaFw6M11JosLCBBO@5v5InaHloYnJ5ObOmTnn3HMLN6WsrvnNTOTczCcuL1IJIevORRDy5HRVU3IiEs5md4/Ca8c74c257f3w6d76/PLJwlJ4dWPlcHHrAMVUrSSiKeRS3b6Q5AjIssPrDzj8vnhGLwqqoGpCTkxmi2JQLqvOUFmNRv3Oack1gPi1j8oMHVKyMUXxxSXPVSGvMvkZJElmocitMiICagCuAb0H3ACjCYSdTyC3gO@APABtA/0C@gjkHWgXcAtIhTcWgln/Dbhq0xludHgllmAbSOcXaGv2e/ZEqgN6l8ty6xeg9b@faW/oiDxpLamn0iK6LmUmvUEkxXxKXJImRnnIBxCW5JVXNsS4PQvGZjLexkQrgMddK7zHT4NReqMM@NnmMllrQUYLcN0OYC2ONrkaq7TRl7US9vfLibX/pjd/AA)

Comment: python won't complain if you remove the space between `39` and `if`; it's even shorter if you replace if-else with the and-or trick

Comment: 175 bytes by replacing `i and int(i,27)%15472%39or 0` with `int(i or'0')%15472%39` --- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU/LSsNAFP2VbOLMWG1tGtOYweL7/X5r7KK2DZlSkxLjQnBhFR8rdec2M90JYrsQKvg190diYlpBL5fL4dx7zuE2LnzbdXKhNX4c1kunJ5WSZBsIpWsuczCSNle2lmcPl47W93YPpiidp/uTC5SuLdKotunO6vQGpTNzyGSOj5nkemgEDSl5ImdH1bwi58aKlutJTGJO37Jse1hTU0zWU5gNaCrJZHSSSthLJmvqoBIvsopOCgWV9OWSbRqGUiTps0ad@RhNIELChhfHWhiBaEFwA@IRgjto3QOP@h34NQQPwJ9AtEF8gHgG/gaiC8Er8KsYJEwQ4U8Imj15xLc68eSJYRt45w/Z8/zB0Yo3@/JubBtHv4C4/X8svn4TUbrqlN1KFaNz3xrOaoiYilGM/vkG "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: And 174 bytes by assigning `''.join` to a variable  --- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU/LTsJAFP2VburMCBYptWAnEN/v91uRBQJNp8GW1LowcSEaHyt157Yz3ZkYYWGCiV9zfwRbQRK9ubk5Ofeec3IbF77lOpmumT/u1sunJ9WyZCXtPEKK7TLHsDGSNle2lmcPl47W93YPpiidp/uTC5SuLdKotunO6vQGpTNzqMgcHzPJ9dAoSqpZIqfHtKwqZ8ZLputJTGKOZOOK5WFdSzA5l8BsSNdIKpUjiR57yWRdG1bjRVrNkUJBIwOlVTQMtUSUs0ad@RhNIEK6DS9ONDECEUJwA@IRgjsI74FH/Q78GoIH4E8gWiA@QDwDfwPRgeAV@FUMekwQ4U8Imn15xIftePKeYQt4@w/Z9/zB0Yo3f@Wd2DaOfgFx@/9YfA0SkVJzKm61htG5b46kdUSKqlGK/vkG "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 12):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>148 146 143</s>  142 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @ngn*

```js
s=>[...s].map(c=>g((k=c.charCodeAt()/8)&8|k*8&7)&g(k&7|k/2&8),o=x='',g=n=>x=n?x*27+n:!(o+=' DZQGYWXNHJ.CSTIO.AFB.LPVE..KUMR'[x%854%89%35]))&&o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVRbTxNBFH7nV1QStrsUlwQlVJPFIN7v9xvy0FSoWuwSSkwfeCgQWp7ABxt80DCz@2AkUSDGpBp/zfkjdWbOmUuhDTFpJtPZc/3Od763hfeFanHpzeLy6Ur8aq4zH3Wq0eRMGIbV2fBdYdEvRpMl3y9HxbD4urA0LWymlv1gNB94@ZXycN6bCLySX/YmVsqjY14@GImjWpTNjpSiSjRZiyoXasNjE7nK@VN@nIuymUsv7l99/vTZnWs3wumHj67fDaeuXAxv3XtyOQxvPr79IDtTG8qPnx3Knxs6Mz4bBJ4Xd4pxpRovzIULcckfyGTm/UFIUmDrkGwBa0DaBC5@@8DXgG0C34bkAJJfkHwA/h2SNrA94HV5wRcm7r@BrZK7eE8P5ckx4AHww65Hiqnu4hNf1e5tGVam3oFk46hx8tfNOBhkcpnsy0o2k6MORNWUE4OpM91VTi1bKf8BvEHNia/yZd@psU324j3dlpbUE0bbA7ZhaxFe6Tf6ayPv0FfRrgRGucsU4t4E1uwqgOu/ohLesC0wcYqSsBgM5cDQq3vKo5NLGBDfHWAfaZxsTWOjhi2TtLWZKge/CmMRjUbepknbwZj4mg3oLoJ3dabudgiGKFsaPx1fDkfd5RD6zu14x5TBcLI7DI22qWe2CemX7l4VYP8PNMXTTEdzyZYmschwCbfEcKYHtXVy4yIbxkXpT1cMiACZprtwdNaLOCxi/gT2CfhnZ1nFmBuSkKaX4zNWuXpA71ixFu2NQcKCjuUYDJBdhvgqAu4QLYpBLlEkRHsEwMloDbaAKyxFcFojVC7UFNW0Cwz68rqzZybjxskrVdciqRfLlG@ww0b5V1WdVhNECE@XfkdElVa2rsaMWLo6iQxwcDUw0Iz7L8JJO4Tig5tpRBpV0eibPOtKvgyB6464aDAIzRb5Wuo6DMAhoRgaEtLMFMDScb3fPMhbc0nIjvuCoCR/NASa8qSvu7SpRg8pwq5VfSPYckg4ddwPXak1VvgShHop@0sGscINf0Qd9QJZUAzr@0/QQb63CrW0mOkXpJgNORB0/gE)

Comment: `g((k=c.charCodeAt())&7|k/8&8)&g(k/8&7|k/16&8)` -> `g((k=c.charCodeAt()/8)&8|k*8&7)&g(k&7|k/2&8)`

Comment: @ngn Thanks :) Merged with another pending optimization.

Comment: May I ask, how did you come up with the brilliant `x%854%89%35`? Did you try many different random moduli?

Comment: @ngn I've tried _m0 < 1000_, _m1 < m0_, _m2 < m1_ (actually with some other optimizations, but that's the idea). And for the factor by which _x_ is multiplied: _[4,6,8,9,10,11,12]_ and _[15...31]_. Currently trying some other approaches.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>305</s> <s>302</s> <s>301</s> <s>286</s> <s>251</s> <s>198</s> 182 bytes

```python
def f(s,A=''):
 for c in s:l=bin(ord(c))[-8:];A+='7'+l[5:]+l[1]+'7'+l[2:5]+l[0]
 print(''.join('K.L.SXC PRU.NYEOGZVJIW..HFBTAQDM'[int('7'+c,22)%141%109%35]for c in A.split('70000')))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVRbT1NBEH7nV5wXcnoCnlCQqDU81Lt4v19IXyw21pCWAC@@FQgtT@CDDT5ounvOg5FEgRiTavw180fq7M7s7B4Em2azZ3fm25lvvpnld2tv2q2Z0WjxdSNqlFYnq3NxnFTGokZ7JapHzVa0Wlmae9Vsldori6V6kiycOV@pXaxOzMXn4omlhdlKDddybYI@pyuz5nuqNhYtrzRba6U4Tt@20Tu@ld5OHz2/HN1/@CS9@@Lqvesvn87ffJamN65delx9cOVOvGDNEaU@OT2djJfPlsfLUxfGZ2ZrEko1XV1eahqrKfzFSZKMGqUYshzUJmQ7oLqQ90Dj/wD0Bqht0LuQHUL2E7L3oL9BNgS1D7pjNnSicP8L1Dq743l@ZFZNgIegjwqHjGn3eKXXnfvQwJqn9yDbOm6c/ZEX42TMxIxx8ivkbtd8YM36Pjb9HXSX08Fbc3IQRDVkezzPd40lZ0Fo@6C2/OvolX/lT4@8x7eYoKHCupsncN8D1SsEoN0nRqK7PgWFK4ZEwRCUT5zzZWT3nEmcONwD9YFLpjYcG7agBnbozGwAdIvGiMZlHXI1PfmC7ypO7gheyMXuPe0ihh3HmMM35bB7Q/vJleIcGVOUVnTk8vVcXbYh/1zMzlL0XzIRwemHQJxoycbIoMfyEJGQ4EUMJ6jUvSguJi/S/Ok6JEDiQTIt0BV0CosTMX@A@gj6U9B3WM2uUZrk8m8p7VuO5OBK9bkLJH1PL8UgiZNyRMYWgTqCZS90ZVZgZE9ZBy96gx3QlkAE56agyUMzwWYaskG@uhN0jby4dUqPdNxkc50iMQtLlJ3@YkNyA4FooTVU17FJyD3YsQUlAsPhRrUOyJTcuZqn69zJptAXNDSov2Sc0jSTuWTWjh07os9OMCIcA8xbn329MoNaUzloiInGuDqWVeO4WWCeXZxUcGKEJ5R@9tsl62TMw3DA3SejjBEGfkTLdDXloPqS5l143tgyybxxoxUanyseAh4bZa4jfO4i43BkBZSePD36bvK4ExIMg4z@Ag)

Comment: [302 (-3 bytes)](https://tinyurl.com/y9fs8rwg)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Thanks :)